# How to add bot to messenger group?

Tags: facebook, bots, chatbot, messenger

How to add chatbot to messenger group ?

I saw that its possible making a private account @ messenger and via VPN bot is active 24/h.

Thansk for any help

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found :
Enabling bots for group chats
By enabling group chat support, your bot will show up in the Add people typeaheads in an existing group chat thread. It will then receive webhooks for each message sent by people in that thread, and can reply to that thread using its thread ID .